# Honda CR-V 2008 disconnect passenger door from central lock

Tags: honda, locks, crv, central-locking

Recently I bought Honda CR-V 2008 and it has a problem with the front passenger door producing a loud cracking sound when locked and unlocked with a central lock (and it doesn't actually get locked and unlocked). The previous owner told me that some time ago he replaced the actuator, it was ok for some time but then the problem reoccured. This makes me think that the root cause may be in something else. It would be ok for me if that door was opened/closed only manually. Is it possible to disconnect this door from central lock either by configuration or by physically unplugging some wire connection?